# When we can compose dl using logarithms and exponential

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I know that composition of dl isn't correct generally,
But I read in my text book that we can do that with logarithms and exponential with some conditions
So what is these conditions? I don't find them in my text book

Comment: wht is a "dl" ?

Comment: Development limité ( development limits)

Comment: Use instead "Taylor n-th order polynomial approximation"

Comment: But there is a way ! I just don't remember it , we can with it use composition , I mean quickly